# how to store syntax in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

1.which data type should be used to store data like group=AB+ ?

```
 E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "group": syntax error SQLiteDatabase: 
 Error inserting 
 district=jhapa phone=9843284985 name=Tom group=AB+
```

2. My table is in this format

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Doners` (\n" +
       "\t`name`\tTEXT,\n" +
       "\t`phone`\tNUMERIC,\n" +
       "\t`group`\tBLOB,\n" +
       "\t`district`\tTEXT\n" +
       ");";
   ```

Comment: Surround AB+ with single quotes.

Comment: it's seems that sqlite doesn't allow to name column name group. i have change column name and everything is fine

Comment: Using a SQL keyword as a column name tends to cause errors unless you're very careful about quoting identifiers, yes. Using a better name is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can either use 
- native SQL via the SQLiteDatabase **execSQL** method 
- the SQLiteDatabase convenience **insert** family of methods :-

- insert (effectively INSERT OR IGNORE)
- insertOrThrow (standard INSERT)
- insertWithOnConflict

  - [SQLiteDatabase - insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

So assuming that you want to insert :-

- ***Tom*** into the **name** column,
- ***9843284985*** into the **phone** column,
- ***AB+*** into the **group** column,

  - ***NOTE*** that **group** is an SQLite keyword and therefore cannot be used and will result in a syntax error, unless it is enclosed [SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)
- ***jhapa***

And that the variable **db** is an instantiated instance of the SQliteDatabase class then :-

you could use :-

```
    db.execSQl("INSERT INTO `Doners` VALUES('Tom',9843284985,'AB+','jhapa')");
```

- noting that a value must be provided for all the defined columns and that the values should be in the order that the columns were defined in.

or you could use :-

```
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Doners (district,phone,name,`group`) VALUES ('jhapa','9843284985','Tom','AB+')");
```

- Here you specify the columns into which the values will be placed, you can specify them in what order you like (values will be inserted according to the order), you can also omit columns (dependant upon the column definition)

  - Defining a column as NOT NULL would require a column and value. However, if a DEFAULT value has been defined as well as NOT NULL then the column can be omitted.

you could use the insert convenience method like :-

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("phone","9843284985");
    cv.put("name","Tom);
    cv.put("`group`","AB+");
    cv.put("district","jhapa");
    long rowid = db.insert("Doners",null,cv);
```

- rowid will be the **rowid** of the inserted row (a unique identifier of the row) or if no row was inserted then **-1**.

  - the convenience method :-
  - it builds the SQL on your behalf
  - protects against SQL injection
  - encloses values accordingly
  - suitable encodes byte[]'s into the the x'ff00fe.......' used by SQL.
  - returns the **rowid** (executes a query using **last_insert_rowid()**).

in regards to :-

> which data type should be used to store data like group=AB+ ?

Due to SQLite's flexibility it probably does not matter what type is assigned to the column. That is with the exception of the **rowid** or an alias of the rowid (the_column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY makes the_column an alias of the **rowid** column) any type of data can be stored in any type of column and to further expand on the flexibility type can be virtually anything (keywords and other syntactically confusing values excepted).

As such `CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn RUMPLESTILTSKIN)` is valid (column has numeric affinity). [see - Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)